# P p-sylow and H a p-subgroup of G

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

> Proposition. If P is a p-sylow of G and H a p-subgroup then $H ∩ N_G(P ) = H ∩ P $

First I try to prove that If $T=H ∩ N_G(P )$ then $TP$ is a p-subgroup of G, how can i prove this and conclude the proposition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$T$ normalizes $P$, and this implies that $TP$ is a subgroup. In fact it is a $p$-subgroup: $|TP|= |T||P|/|T \cap P|$ which number is a power of $p$ since T and P are both $p$-groups. $TP$ is a subgroup of $N_G(P) $ of which $P$ is the unique normal Sylow $p$-subgroup. So $TP \subseteq P $, whence $T \subseteq P$.

Comment: O yea you are right, thanks y proved it :)

Comment: No problem, fun corrollary is that if $P$ and $Q$ are Sylow $p$-subgroups, then $N_P(Q)= P \cap Q = N_Q(P)$.

Comment: Can you check me this please for me is clear the morality but i do not know how to prove the existents with that condition please!http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/520311/p-p-sylow-with-p-zg

Comment: Can you help me in this problem http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/520311/p-p-sylow-with-p-zg , for me the normality is clear but the existents with that conditions is difficult. please.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that since $T \subseteq N_G(H)$ every element of $T$ normalize $H$ and so $TH=HT$, this implies that the *frobenius product* 
$$TH = \{th \mid t \in T, h \in H\}$$ 
is a subgroup.

From this point you should be able to continue your argument.