# P p-sylow with $ P ⊂ Z(G) $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

For me this problem is hard .

If $ P⊂ Z(G)$ is a  $p$-sylow of $G$ then there is a $N$ normal subgroup of $G$ such that  $P ∩ N = 1$ and $G = PN$.

I try use the Schur-Zassenhaus: All normal subgroup cop rime has a complement and all conjugates  are conjugate, but i stuck in this problem please help thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By applying Schur-Zassenhaus to $P$, you can find a subgroup $N$ such that $P \cap N = 1$ and $G = PN$.

Now $P$ is central, so $P$ normalizes $N$. Thus $N$ is normal.

Comment: but the Schur-Zassenhau is direct the exist of a subgroup such that P∩N=1 and G=PN ?

Comment: Yes, it should be straightforward to see that.

Comment: Sorry but I have been trying to prove the existents using Schur's theorem  but i can not conclude this with those properties of the problem, sorry to be so dumb

Comment: please help……..

Comment: I got it!!! thanks!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

P is a normal subgroup, then by Theorem S-Z, G has a subgroup
of order $[G: P]$. Where $| P |$ and $[G: P]$ relatively prime, it follows that 
$ P∩N=1$ and $G=PN$.